# Linear independent matrix space $M_i^{+}M_j$

Tags: matrices

Under what condition of $k,m,n$, we can have $k$ matrices $M_1,\cdots,M_k\in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ such that the $k^2$ matrices $M_i^{+}M_j$ are linear independent? Here, $M^+$ denotes the hermitian conjugate of $M$.

Is $k=m=2n$ enough?

Comment: $M_i^+ M_j \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ which has dimension $n^2$, so you obviously need $k \le n$.

Comment: Taking $M_i =  u e_i^+ $, where $e_i$ are a basis of $\mathbb C^n$ (written as columns) and $u$ a nonzero vector in $\mathbb C^m$,  $M_i^+ M_j$ is a nonzero multiple of $e_i e_j^+$, so $k \le n$ is sufficient.

Comment: @ Robert Israel Thank you very much!